# Will Oracle ignore my index?

Tags: oracle, index, execution-plan

Suppose I have a table (TABLE_1) with some fields, including ID (number), NAME (varchar2) and DATE_TIME (date). There was a need to create a index on those 3 fields to optimize queries like:

```
select * from TABLE_1 where ID = [SOME_VALUE] and NAME = [SOME_VALUE] and DATE_TIME is not null;
```

Because DATE_TIME can have a multitude of different datetime values, I decided to create the index as such:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_TABLE_1 ON TABLE_1 (ID,NAME,TRUNC(DATE_TIME));
```

My question is: will Oracle use this index on the select query or will it ignore it and perform a full table scan on TABLE_1?

EDIT1: I forgot to mention that the ID field is a foreign key.

Comment: Why the downvote and no answer?

Comment: I don't understatnd, why do you not use date_time instead of trunc(date_time)?

Comment: I upvoted the answer below because I feel it is correct.  But, you have a column, ID, which implies either uniqueness, or near uniqueness.  If so, why have multiple columns when you have high selectivity on the ID column?

Comment: @miracle173 I was trying to use the TRUNC(date_time) to avoid a near unique (if not indeed unique) index.

Comment: @unleashed I forgot to mention that the ID field is a foreign key and not the primary key.

Comment: But why do you want to avoid a (near) unique index?

Comment: @user3641702 I don't think the fact it is a foreign key is really relevant to your query performance.  But, as it is an FK, you should have it indexed for other performance reasons.  The question still remains, if ID is near unique, why are you adding the additional fields instead of just using the index on ID alone?

Comment: @miracle173 please correct me if I'm wrong but I was under the impression that an index whose values could fall into some "buckets" had better performance than an index whose values were (nearly) unique

Comment: I don't think that you can improve performance by using truncated data for the index. Where does this information come from?

Comment: @miracle173 this information doesn't come from anywhere in particular. Like I said before, I was under the impression that an index whose values could fall into some "buckets" had better performance and to create those buckets, I could truncate the DATE_TIME field

Comment: No, this does not improve the performance. You shouldn't expect a performance improvement if you remove information from the index. But it can result in a decrease of performance: 1) the query haslarger set of rows, 2) the date component of an index cannot be used at all because your query uses date_time but the index has stored a function of date_time.  You should avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the data distribution. I can easily construct examples for both cases (index vs table scan).

Just think about the case when the columns are unique or nearly unique (index), or when all the rows are the same (table scan).

Technically your index can be used for the above query.

Given the general nature of a column named `ID`, I would say the index will be chosen, but it is not guaraanteed.

The predicate `DATE_TIME is not null` will be processed at the table level, not the index level, even if you make sure that the NULL rows are indexed as well:

```
create index index_1 on table_1(id, name, trunc(date_time), 1);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 852675278

-------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name    |
-------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |         |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TABLE_1 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | INDEX_1 |
-------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("DATE_TIME" IS NOT NULL)
   2 - access("ID"=1 AND "NAME"='Oracle')
```

Comment: Do they need to change the query to `and TRUNC(DATE_TIME) is not null` to align with the index? Or is Oracle optimizer smart to identify that `column is (not) null` is equivalent to `TRUNC(column) is (not) null`?

Comment: Balasz, I think '1- filter("DATE_TIME" IS NOT NULL)' means that Oracle access the row by rowid  from the table to check if the value of "DATE_TIME" is not null. so the fact that the  trunc(date_time) field is not  null is not used.

Comment: @miracle173 Exactly what I said. The original query contains `DATE_TIME is not null`, and not `TRUNC(DATE_TIME) is not null`.

Comment: @BalazsPapp so basically it doesn't matter if DATE_TIME has index, because it will never be used for this field?

Comment: @user3641702 Your predicate contains `DATE_TIME is not null`. But you have `TRUNC(DATE_TIME)` in your index. Even though we know that `TRUNC(DATE_TIME)` returns NULL when `DATE_TIME` is NULL, the database does not have this optimization. If you want an index to be used, include the column `DATE_TIME` in the index, and not `TRUNC(DATE_TIME)`.